# Copy SQL From one Server to another and ignore Duplicatess

Tags: php, mysql, database, cron

I have 2 websites that offer exactly the same content just with different layouts, Im currently updating both sites daily putting the same content on both, I want to make a php script or something similar and run it on a cron to automatically copy the DB from one server to the other server but i don't want it to duplicate the content already there, The Database has a unique field for which it can check against.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything? The two DBs are an exact match?

Comment: why don't you have them both share the same db? otherwise use replication: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html. 2 sites same content why? sounds like spam or scam or poor marketing effort.

Comment: If they both share the same DB and the main site goes down then that means both sites are down. There are millions of sites out there with the same content, Dosen't mean they are all scam sites. The sites are completly different layouts/designs so person A might like getting the content from Site A, where as Person B may find it easier to access Site B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have only the 1 database, with 2+ templates (skins) for displaying the content. Duplicating the same data in production, when there are no differences between the data sets, is somewhat pointless.

--EDIT-- May 15, 2012 @ 7:06 PM ET
If you *REALLY* want to maintain duplicate production db's, I would suggest a web service that sends the data from one site to another. You can also think about using a trigger in your db. It really does depend on your setup, where the web server(s) are located, the DB server(s), etc.

Comment: There are reasons for duplication, namely for disaster recovery.  Having both online at the same time means that if one goes down, then the other is instantly available.  Replication is the right solution.

Comment: Hello, I don't personally see it as pointless, Im just looking for a solution to my problem. Thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: That's part of what DB backups are for. Disaster recovery. And it's not completely pointless. For instance, we duplicate our data to non-production servers here multiple times a day (depending on the DB size, i.e. over 100 million records in one DB alone, sometimes only twice per day). There are some use cases for maintaining two db's in production, I will grant you.

Comment: *a web service that sends the data from one site to another* Yeah, a web service written in Java that serializes changes to XML and deserializes to SQL statements, right? Just use replication.

Comment: I never said it was a _good_ way of doing it... just _A_ way of doing it.